# How to schedule a Task in Php (Non-repetitive)?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

Hello I want to schedule a task in Php. I have a Web Restful Api in which I want to schedule a Task at a specific time (only once not repetitive). How can I do it?

Can I do it with Crone Job, even though the tutorials I found show mostly for repetitive tasks.

Thanks

Comment: If possible can you send me sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of schedule a task just with PHP.
IDEA: In your DB you can save time stamps, run what you want when the time stamps gets smaller than "time()" and then update the time stamp to the next run (after each time you run your code).

Comment: doesn't that mean I have to check the database everytime?
FYI I am using a RestFul API service

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the best practice in your case and yes, or you can pass the values as arguments in the cron itself.
I don't really know what the full purpose of your code so I can't recommend more then I just did for other best practice.